# Django rest framework API permission

Tags: django, rest, frameworks

I would like to limit the access to myweb/api in Django rest framework.

I've tried:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )
}
```

But it limits all the requests however I want to limit access only to  myweb/api page.

Comment: look at this tutorial https://godjango.com/43-permissions-authentication-django-rest-framework-part-2/

Comment: You may specify permission classes for each view under myweb/api. There're 2 examples here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#setting-the-permission-policy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add liberal permissions in settings.py file and add more restrictive ones in the specific api view.

In settings.py, add something like :

```
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly'
),
```

of you could also use `AllowAny` permission.

> You can set the authentication policy on a per-view, or per-viewset basis, using the APIView class based views.

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class ExampleView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        content = {
            'status': 'request was permitted'
        }
        return Response(content)
```

> Or, if you're using the @api_view decorator with function based views.

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.response import Response

@api_view('GET')
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated, ))
def example_view(request, format=None):
    content = {
        'status': 'request was permitted'
    }
    return Response(content)
```

> When you set new permission classes through class attribute or decorators you're telling the view to ignore the default list set over the settings.py file.